# How to solve JNI crashes on a Linux machine without core dumps

Tags: java, c, linux, java-native-interface, coredump

I'm working on a program, where the Java part launches C++ code using JNI interface. This program is installed on a Linux machine (CentOS), but while launching the program (using "java "), I see the following:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x06da0fdd, pid=4970, tid=3086470032
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_60-b19) (build 1.7.0_60-    b19)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.60-b09 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libmain_project.so+0x782fdd]  _Z8ulm_initPKcb.part.6+0x393
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
...
```

In order to have more information, I have already added the line `ulimit -c unlimited` just before launching the Java class, but that seems not to work. (it seems that in some shells the command `ulimit` is replaced by `limit`)

About the structure of the main project: every *.c file has been compiled into an *.o file (using g++). Different *.o files are grouped into *.a files (ar archives), and those have then been collected into one big libmain_project.so file, again using g++.

I have already found the *.o file which contains the "_Z8ulm_initPKcb.part.6" part:

```
$ nm -AC ulm.o | grep ulm_init
...
ulm.o:0000216e T ulm_init(char const*, bool)
ulm.o:00001c52 t _Z8ulm_initPKcb.part.6
```

This indicates that there are two "ulm_init" instances within the ulm.o file, but while having a look into the ulm.c file, I only find the following function:

```
void *ulm_init(const char* szVersion, bool bAllocDaemonCoexistence)
```

Which is called once:

```
void ulm_map_init(const char* szVersion) {
   ulm_init(szVersion);
}
```

My problems are:

How can I found out the meaning of _Z8ulm_initPKcb.part.6 (what does this "part.6" stand for?)?

Even once I know what it stands for, how can I start calculating the "+0x393"? I have already tried to have a look at the ulm.o code:

```
Prompt>nm -AC ulm.o | sort
ulm.o:00001c52 t _Z8ulm_initPKcb.part.6
ulm.o:0000216e T ulm_init(char const*, bool)
```

As you can see, 1c52 + 0x393 < 216e => so the problem should be located within _Z8ulm_initPKcb.part.6, but how to interprete this?

Comment: If you put the symbol `_Z8ulm_initPKcb` into [an online name demangler](https://demangler.com/) you will get`ulm_init(char const*, bool)`. So if you have a problem it's in the `ulm_init` function. Start looking *at the source* for the function, and if it doesn't look out of place ask someone else to look at the source. And if both of you think the function is okay, then look at how it's called, can it be called with a null or otherwise illegal or uninitialized pointer?

Comment: Meanwhile I've found out that the "part.x" suffix means that partial inlining has been executed, which is an optimisation technique. By modifying the optimisation options (e.g. -O0 for disabling all optimisations) during compilation, those suffixes can be avoided.